# find/discover + object + to infinitive / past participle

Tags: infinitives, past-participles

Examples from Quirk:

**1.** *They found him worn out by travel and exertion*.

**2.** *They discovered him worn out by travel and exertion*.

---

My remade sentences with "*to be*":

**1a.** *They found him **to be** worn out by travel and exertion*.

**2a.** *They discovered him **to be** worn out by travel and exertion*.

---

What is the difference between **1.** and **1a.**?

What is the difference between **2.** and **2a.**?

Thanks!

---

My thoughts:

"*find*" + object + to infinitive ([oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/find_1?q=find)):

**to find** - to discover that something is true after you have tried it, tested it or experienced it:

*They found him to be charming*.

---

"*discover*" + object + to infinitive ([thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/discover)):

**to discover** - to learn something about:

*discovered him to be an impostor*

*discovered the brake to be defective*

---

My sentences with "*that*":

**1b.** *They found (**that**) he was worn out by travel and exertion*.

**2b.** *They discovered (**that**) he was worn out by travel and exertion*.

---

I conclude that:

**1.** = **1.a** = **1.b** = **2.** = **2.a** = **2.b**

What mistakes do my thoughts have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this depends on what *they* were actively doing.

If *they* were *looking* for *him* (i.e. because *he* was lost/missing), then both sentences **1** and **2** describe two facts:

1. that *they* were successful in their search
2. that *he* was worn out (fatigued) from travel and exertion

If *they* were *studying* *him* (e.g. because *he* reported feeling unwell), then the sentences describe two *different* facts:

1. that *they* determined the reason
2. the reason was that *he* was worn out (fatigued) from travel and exertion.

Compare and contrast some of the dictionary definitions:

> **[Find (v)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find)**
>
> 1. to come upon by searching or effort
> 2. to discover by study or experiment
> 3. to determine and make a statement about

with:

> **[Find out (v)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find%20out)**
>
> 1. to learn by study, observation, or search
> 2. to ascertain the true character or identity of

The use of **that** and **to be** in *your* sentences (**1a**, **1b**, **2a** and **2b**) align more with the notion of study and experiment, and that *their* [**finding**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finding) was that *he* was worn out.

While sentences **1** and **2** *could* refer to either action (both *searching* and *studying* are referenced in the definitions for **find**), I am inclined to read them as the meaning *first* action (that they were looking for him); while sentences **1a**, **1b**, **2a** and **2b** all lead me to the *second* action (that they were studying him).

As such, I would suggest that **1** = **2**, and that **1a** = **1b** = **2a** = **2b**, but *not necessarily* that **1** = **1a** or **1b**, nor that **2** = **2a** or **2b**.

That said, if I were writing these sentences, I would also deploy a comma in sentences *1* and *2*, to make it less ambiguous:

1. They found him, worn out by travel and exertion.
2. They discovered him, worn out by travel and exertion.

Comment: You have a good logic and ability to explain. Thank you very much. I wish I could vote up your answer, but my reputation score is not enough.